# ¿Por qué en una función anidada debo retornarla en su función principal?

Tags: javascript, funciones, clausuras

Estoy aprendiendo sobre funciones, pero en el libro que me estoy leyendo (como preámbulo) me habla de las funciones anidadas y que para llamar una función interna, es necesario los doble parentesis. Solo que viendo el código, me di cuenta que **`test`** retorna a **`saludar`**, cosa que si no lo hago, me tira error cuando intento usar **`test()()`**

> función indefinida

¿Por qué esto es así?

```js
function test() {
 var name = "pepe";

 function saludar() {
  return "hola " + name;
 }
 return saludar; // ¿?
}
console.log(test()());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función la explicaré en tres escenarios

1. Al invocar el nombre de la función Padre o la principal, de este modo test(), le indicamos que ejecute el la lógica completa que tiene por dentro, pero dentro de ella misma es otra función por lo cual el resultado daría

```js
function test() {
  var name = "pepe";
  
  function saludar() {
    return "hola " + name;
  }
  
  return saludar; // ¿?
}

console.log(test());
```

El resultado sería como tal el cuerpo de la función hija que contiene así

> function saludar() {   return "hola " + name; }

2. Cuando ejecutamos test()() con doble pareja de parentesis, estamos indicando que ejecute dicha función, pero que así mismo ejecute una función que viene por dentro para que en vez de retornarnos el cuerpo de saludar() solo nos vevuelva Hola pepe

```js
function test() {
  var name = "pepe";
  
  function saludar() {
    return "hola " + name;
  }
  
  return saludar; // ¿?
}

console.log(test()());
```

Retornaría la lógica que es ejecutar un mensaje personalizado

**¿Por qué necesito un return?**

> Las funciones pueden devolver un estado o valor explicito que ha sido procesado por lo cual
>   al momento de ejecutar test() necesitamos también el valor de
>   saludar(); si no ejecutamos el return al momento de hacer un
>   console.log(test()()), va a estar esperando ejecutar una función
>   interna; pero la misma nunca esta siendo devuelta o retornada por la
>   función padre

Lo siguiente marcará error

```
function test() {
  var name = "pepe";

  function saludar() {
    return "hola " + name;
  }

  //return saludar; // ¿?
}

console.log(test()());
```

En el siguiente ejemplo, vamos a obtener el valor de **undefined** por que estamos pidiendo la ejecuión de la lógica que contiene test(), pero esta misma no tiene ningún valor de vuelta o retornado

```
function test() {
  var name = "pepe";

  function saludar() {
    return "hola " + name;
  }

  //return saludar; // ¿?
}

console.log(test());
```

> Return existe por que en este ejemplo en especifico, se espera que
>   cuando test()() sea invocada a través de console.log() deberá traer la
>   lógica procesada que tiene en su interior, la cual a su vez es otra
>   función; una función hija. La doble pareja de parentesis existe por
>   que ejecutamos en orden: primero la función padre `test()` y luego la
>   función hija `saludar()`

Answer (score 2):

La funcion `test` contiene a la función `saludar`, esta función solo es accesible dentro de la función `test`.

La función `test` devuelve una función anónima que en esta caso es saludar.

Si tu haces `console.log(test())` podrás comprobar que te regresa dicha función anónima

```js
function test() {
  var name = "pepe";
  
  function saludar() {
    return "hola " + name;
  }
  
  return saludar; // ¿?
}

console.log(test());
//ver la consola para ver la prueba
```

Ahora bien tu podrías almacenar esta misma función en otra variable e invocarla cuando tu quisieras, sin embargo se verá que por simplicidad se ejecuta en la misma función

```js
function test() {
  var name = "pepe";
  
  function saludar() {
    return "hola " + name;
  }
  
  return saludar; // ¿?
}

const funcionSaludar = test();
console.log(funcionSaludar())
console.log(test()());
```

PD podrás notar que en el return de `test` retorna `saludar;` sin paréntesis, esto quiere decir que va a retornar la función anónima y no su ejecución.

Answer (score 1):

En javascript es posible que una funcion retorne otra funcion, entonces para obtener el resultado de la funcion de retorno debes invocarla, por ello los dos parentesis.

```
let saludar=test();// te devuelve la funcion saludar 
//ahora podes invocar a la funcion saludar
saludar();
```

Comment: Ya, lo comprendo. Pero como en el libro se refiere a llamar "una función interna", no de obtener el resultado de la función de retorno. Osea que si por ejemplo, tengo otra función igual que la de saludar, pero lo contrario (despedir) y la deseo llamar, me imagino que no se puede y que el libro se equivoco en la explicación, supongo. ¿No?

Comment: @TottiTP puedes poner un ejemplo por que no entiendo tu pregunta